# installing matlab 2014 on ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: matlab

I am facing problem while installing matlab 2014b on Ubuntu 14.04. After mounting the iso file, and through terminal when I type `./install` I get `permission denied`. And when I type `sudo ./install` then I get `sudo: ./install command not found`. I just don't understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must first `cd` to the relevant directory before running the install script.

```
cd /path/to/folder

sudo ./install
```

Alternatively, you may not have the necessary permissions to execute the file.

```
chmod +x install

sudo ./install
```

Comment: indeed i did cd to relevant folder, and only after that am I getting the above responses..

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to copy the files after mounting the iso image to a new directory

Like

```
/tmp/matlab
```

and then run by

```
./install
```

Hope it works